# how to assign different title to two blog in same installation

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I have installed wordpress on my server and i am using two blogs with different category in each on the same installation. I have assign two different names to two blog page but now i am not able to assign different name for the post detail page. For example

1) If some body clicking on the post of the blog page 1 it should need to have blog page 1 as a title.

2) Respectively if some body clicking on the posts of the blog page 2 it should need to display title as blog page 2.

Please help me it and also let me know if you need further info.

Thanks & Regards

I am using this code for title

```
<div class="title">

    <div id="title">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="crumbs">
        <?php crumbs(); ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What did you tried yet? Post some code, which you tried and did not work please so we can help you.

Comment: sure i will post here @rsz

Comment: i have added the code please review it @rsz

Answer (score 0):

How about add 'echo' to print function restult?

```
<div class="title">

    <div id="title">
        <h1><?php echo the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="crumbs">
        <?php echo crumbs(); ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: my code is working fine the only thing i want to change the title of the posts. for example if some body clicking on posts of blog page 1 posts title should display blog page 1 as title respectively if some body clicking on posts of blog page 2 post title should display as blog page 2.

Comment: ok, maybe you can try this with js, Are you tried something? post some more code.